# Why does my code need <iostream>?

Tags: c++, iostream

I wrote some basic code I learned that can be used to define a type that gets an enumerated value as its constructor argument and has a member function `AsString()` that returns the value as a string.

The code doesn't compile unless I include `<iostream>`. It displays a warning in `main` saying that the type `color` has not been declared. Why is it required to include an input/output header file in my code while no input/output functions or operators are used in it?

```
enum ColorEnum {blue, red};

class color
{
    protected:
        ColorEnum value;
    public:
        color(ColorEnum initvalue)
        {
            value = initvalue;
        }
        std::string AsString()
        {
            switch (value)
            {
                case blue:
                    return "blue";
                case red:
                    return "red";
                default:
                    return "N/A";
            }
        }
};

int main()
{
    color mycolor = blue;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is that ALL of your code, or did you remove something? You should have an include for <string> at least, surely?

Comment: What did you also #include (provide full example, please), e.g. string is missing (where is <string>)

Comment: By the way: I would recommend to start the class name color with an uppercase C => Color. It is also typical in the C++ world to use lowercase method names (except in some Microsoft APIs), AsString() would be named asString() by most developers (this is for C++, other languages has other conventions) or implement operators instead of the explicit conversion method.

Comment: Why is it better to start with an uppercase letter? I've heard that many times, but I don't see the logic behind it.

Comment: @Beachwalker It is also typical in the C++ world to use a zillion of other different conventions. Don't let yourself be fooled by your bubble of experience.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes ... was only a recommendation. Look how "most" people/books did it. Anyway you could also name your class cOlOr, but this does not increase readability. I would prefer code that is easy to read and follows a convention most other programmers use, too. I don't know what your bubble is - I can only speak for mine. (http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Naming, http://www.possibility.com/Cpp/CppCodingStandard.html)

Comment: @Beachwalker Naming conventions are _personnal_. The only thing that matters is that everyone on your team follows the same convention.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not need `<iostream>`, you need `<string>` for `std::string`, which you may be getting indirectly via `<iostream>`.

Comment: answered 18 secs ago

Luchian Grigore, answered 18 secs ago

juanchopanza lol :)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore same answer too. But I think you beat me by a split second.

Comment: And I wrote essentially the same thing in a comment :(

Comment: second, no. Milliseconds, maybe :)

Comment: Does `<iostream>` itself include `<string>`? If yes, I guess that was my problem because I thought `<iostream>` was only for input/output streaming.

Comment: @MohammadSanei it is not specified to include `<string>`, and it doesn't in the compilers I use these days. But I have old memories of `<iostream>` including strings on some compiler many years ago... Try including `<string>` and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: It did fix the problem, thanks. You mean in newer compilers I must include both `<string>` and `using namespace std` just to be able to declare a string variable?

Comment: @MohammadSanei You have to `#include <string>`, but you shouldn't `use namespace std`. Just call it `std::string`.

Comment: @MohammadSanei more on `using namespace std` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c).

Comment: Thanks. I think my `<iostream>` includes the `<string>` file. But it's weird I don't see the line `#include <string>` when I look inside my `<iostream>`.

Comment: @MohammadSanei: MSVC's `iostream` includes a header that has `std::string` defined in it, but does not actually include the `string` header itself.  Many consider this a poor decision on Microsoft's part.

Comment: @MooingDuck That's not the case with my compiler which is CodeBlocks because I always need to add `std::` to my string types whether I include `<string>` or `<iostream>`. My `<iostream>` seems to include `<string>` rather than define `std::string`. But I don't see the inclusion statement anywhere in the `<iostream>` file or its include files.

Comment: No matter what header you include, you should always have to type `std::`.  `iostream` needs to define `std::string` to work, period.  However, it doesn't have to do that by including the `string` header directly.  In MSVC, `std::string` is defined in the `xstring` header, which both the `string` header and `iostream` include. (Your header names will differ since you're using codeblocks)

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to include `<iostream>`, but `<string>`, because you use `std::string`, so that might set the compiler off.

If you include `<string>` and still get the error, that sounds like a bug in the compiler.

Comment: OK, we'll need a cage to determine which answer wins.

Comment: More specifically, there should also be another error complaining about a missing definition for `std::string` - or, more likely still, the compiler will have complained about an "incomplete type" instead of an "undefined type"